# Trailing double quotes in AngularJS expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've found this [highly upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796341/set-angular-scope-variable-in-markup/28432472#28432472) (+50) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665319/how-to-set-a-variable-inside-of-a-template#comment54563800_16665319) suggesting that ending an expression with a semicolon and double quotes, *i.e.* `;""`, could be used when you want to define an Angular variable in your template without rendering it as text.

I've tested and it works. Example:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="">
  <p>This variable is rendered: {{ text1 = 'yes' }}   </p>
  <p>This variable isn't:       {{ text2 = 'yes';"" }}</p>  
</div>
```

I know that using [ngInit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16665698/1476885) is the best approach to initialize a variable, but +50 users upvoted the other suggestion and [I'm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665319/how-to-set-a-variable-inside-of-a-template#comment58716334_35512817) wondering: is this a documented feature? I could not find any reference to this.

If it isn't a feature and rather a rendering **bug** that people are taking advantage of, should I assume that it isn't safe to use and likely to be fixed in the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a rendering **bug**. When multiple expressions are separated by a semicolon the Angular expression evaluates to the last expression.

```
 {{a=5; x=4; z="hello"}} evaluates to {{"hello"}}

 {{ text2 = 'yes';"" }} evaluates to {{""}}
```

An empty string is not rendered.

That behavior is not going to go away.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I've misunderstood the `;""` as a special command. Thx.